# Sending multiple query results to res.render() using node-mysql and mysql-queue

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I [new to `node.js` and programming in general] have two `mysql` query results (member info and list of workshops that members can attend) and need to send them to `res.render()` to be presented in `.jade` template (Member edit page).

To do this I'm using `node-mysql` and `mysql-queue` modules. Problem is I don't know how to pass callback function to render the response before `queue.execute()` finishes so I made workaround and put first two queries in the queue (mysql-queue feature), executed the queue, and afterwards added third "**dummy query**" which has callback function that renders the template.

My question is can I use this workaround and what would be the proper way to this using this modules?

```
exports.memberEdit = function (req, res) {

    var q = connection.createQueue();

    var membersResults,
        htmlDateSigned,
        htmlBirthDate,
        servicesResults;

    q.query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id= ?;", req.id, function (err, results) {
      console.log("Članovi: " + results[0]);
      membersResults = results[0];
      htmlDateSigned = dater.convertDate(results[0].dateSigned);
      htmlBirthDate = dater.convertDate(results[0].birthDate);
    });

    q.query("SELECT * FROM services", function (err, results) {
      console.log("Services: " + results);
      servicesResults = results;
    });

    q.execute();

    // dummy query that processes response after all queries and callback execute 
   // before execute() statement
    q.query("SELECT 1", function (err,result) {
    res.render('memberEdit', { title: 'Edit member', 
                               query:membersResults, 
                               dateSigned:htmlDateSigned,   
                               birthDate:htmlBirthDate,
                               services:servicesResults }); 
})
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an alternative could be to use a [transaction](https://github.com/bminer/node-mysql-queues#clientstarttransaction) to wrap your queries with:

```
var trans = connection.startTransaction();
trans.query(...);
trans.query(...);
trans.commit(function(err, info) {
  // here, the queries are done
  res.render(...);
});
```

`commit()` will call `execute()` *and* it provides a callback which will be called when all query callbacks are done.

This is still a bit of a workaround though, it would make more sense if `execute()` would provide the option of passing a callback (but it doesn't). Alternatively, you could use a module which provides a Promise implementation, but that's still a workaround.